# Don't print the last character: print only after the next input

Tags: c, buffering

I have a problem, when I try to print an input, the program doesn't print the last string (in this case `var_quantita`).

But if I add an `\n`, or if I send another command from `stdin`, it works.

So I think that the problem is related to the last string, but I'm not sure.

My code:

```
uint32_t var_quantita;
uint8_t var_tipo[BUF_SIZE];
//...
memset(com_par, 0, BUF_SIZE);
memset(comando, 0, BUF_SIZE);
memset(arg2, 0, BUF_SIZE);
memset(arg3, 0, BUF_SIZE);
memset(arg4, 0, BUF_SIZE);

//prendo in ingresso il comando e i parametri
fgets(com_par, BUF_SIZE, stdin);

sscanf(com_par, "%s %s %s %s", comando, arg2, arg3, arg4);
printf("Argomenti inviati:%s %s %s %s \n", comando, arg2, arg3, arg4);

//......

if(strcmp(comando, "add\0") == 0){

    strcpy(var_tipo, arg2);
    var_quantita = atoi(arg3);
    printf("Tipo:%s\nQuantita:%d", var_tipo, var_quantita); 


}//fine if(add)
```

Comment: Output to the terminal is often buffered. Sending a `\n` flushes the output buffer. Try this or, `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Yes, with the {\n} it works, but i don't know: is the correct mode? Or is like to pass over the problem?

Comment: fflush is the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffering of your system is set to be line buffered, characters are transmitted from the buffer as a block when a new-line character is encountered. Using `\n` is perfectly valid, but it has the side effect of also printing a newline, there are other options, namely:

- Using `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf` will flush the buffer regarless, you won't need `\n`.
- You can change your buffering mode to have no buffering, each output is written as soon as possible. Again, no `\n` will be needed.

  ```
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
  ```

Comment: Ok thanks! I didn't konw if the { \n } was valid!